# AngularJS - run task in background repeatedly

Tags: angularjs

I am relatively new to AngularJS.

A current usecase I am working on involves running a function every N seconds, as long as the user has the browser window open. This background service must not in itself interfere with the rest of the app.

What is the preferred way to do this in AngularJS?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for the $interval service: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval

Comment: You could start the $interval within the .run() service, or create a factory to hold the interval timeout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) as mentioned by @dustyrockpyle.

Note that using a regular `setInterval` with AngularJS is usually not a good idea, as Angular won't automatically notice any changes made.